# Hopf-Borel theorem over polynomial rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

There is a theorem of Borel saying that:

For a connected cocommutative Hopf algebra $A$ over the perfect field $k$ such that underlying graded vector space is finite-dimensional over $k$ we have that 
$$A=\otimes_i A_i$$
where each $A_i$ is a Hopf algebra with a single generator

The question is - does this result hold if we replace $k$ with $k[t]$
and consider a connected cocommutative Hopf algebra $A$ over $k[t]$ such that $A$ is free as $k[t]$-module